# Lua string.format %c versus string.char

Tags: lua, string.format, openwrt

Should Lua `string.format( "%c", value )` be equivalent to `string.char( value )`?

It seems not when character value is zero.

```
string.format( "%c", 0 ):len()
```

returns 0

```
string.char( 0 ):len()
```

returns 1

Even stranger,

```
string.format( "%c%s", 0, "abc" ):len()
```

**returns 3**; where any other non-zero-modulo-256 value for %c returns 4, so `string.format` is not truncating the whole string at null byte like C `sprintf`, just collapsing `%c` field to empty string instead of one-byte string. Note that C `sprintf` writes the zero byte followed by the abc bytes in this case.

I couldn't find anything in the Lua docs describing expected behavior in this case. Most other string handling in Lua seems to treat zero byte as valid string character.

This is on Lua 5.1.4-8 on OpenWrt.

Idiosyncracy or bug?

Comment: What does `("%c%s"):format(0, "abc"):sub(1, 1)` give?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a bug.

In Lua 5.1 and LuaJIT 2.0, `string.format` formats one item at a time (using the `sprintf` provided by the host C runtime.) It then calls `strlen` to update the length of the output string.  Since `strlen` stops at the null character, this character will be overwritten.

This is documented behaviour for `%s`, but probably unintentional for `%c`

This is fixed in Lua 5.2.  I wouldn't expect any more updates to 5.1.

Comment: Note that Lua 5.2 only fixes %c, but not %s. LuaJIT 2.1 handles this correctly for **both** %c and %s.

Answer (score 0):

In the book "programming in lua" 2nd edition. In the chapter 2.4, there are some context like below:
"Strings in Lua have the usual meaning: a sequence of characters. Lua is
eight-bit clean and its strings may contain characters with any numeric code,
including embedded zeros. This means that you can store any binary data into
a string.
"

So this is not a bug

Comment: I interpret that statement to mean "embedded zeros are treated just like any other byte".  But the documentation of `string.format` is more relevant here, because it states an exception to this rule.